# Data Migration from a non-normalized table to a normalized table

Tags: sql-server, migration, normalization

I have a non-normalized table that show the car sales detailing car makes, models and sub models. Because it's not normalized, instead of having the IDs that refer to car makes, models and sub models, it has the real values. These values are entered manually, in an old application that is going to be migrated, by an employee so there can be many problems like misspelling, similar words, spaces, dashes, etc.

I created a normalized table and I need to migrate the existing data from the non-normalized table to the new, normalized table. I need to find the IDs corresponding to each value (ID for car make, model and sub model). But, this is not so easy because, for example, Audi (car make) A4 (car model) 1.8T (sub model) could be written as Audi A4 1.8Turbo or Audi A4 1.8Turbo Injection or Audi A4 1.8 TFI, etc. So, many different text values for the same entity. 
I think that the best option to get the IDs, considering the context given above, is to have an alias table for each entity. For example, CarSubModelAlias. These tables would specify all the different values that map to the same entity.
Unfortunately, I have more than 3,500 sub models and it's really hard to populate that tables.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: It will always be an element of data cleansing involved in cases like this. SSIS could be a good option to successively reduce the problem, by first extracting all the perfect matches and then pass the remaining rows through a fuzzy lookup to find best matches.

Answer (score 1):

Jayvee is correct, The best way is to develop a SSIS package. Use Exact Match and Fuzzy Match component to match the source data with destination. This way you could normalize the data as well.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I'm not sure that SSIS is going to work in this case because the reference name could be really different to the text value. For example:
Reference value: 1.8T 
Text value: 1.8 Turbo Injection FI

I'm analyzing the Levenshtein algorithm for comparing strings (.NET implementation of the algorithm: http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein). I'm thinkg about a small console application that gets the first N characters of the text value (N is the length of the reference value) and compare them using this algorithm.
What do you think?

Comment: I checked the Levenshtein algorithm but it's not working very well with some cases. It's confusing 1.8 with 1.8T because, according to this algorithm, the distance is just 1 and 1.8T and 1.8 T have a distance of 2.
I think that I'm gonna create a Windows application showing all the mapping options ordered by distance so the user can choose the best option (manual interaction). By default, the one with the lowest distance is going to be selected.

Comment: I am not sure if you have already resolved this but using Script component in SSIS you could also write your own rules to match the two keywords like “1.8T” and “1.8 T”. For this we can develop a DLL and add reference to that dll in SSIS script component and then we can split the final result into good and bad matches.

Comment: I developed a small tool to manage data mapping because some cases cannot be matched and need human intervention. My tool matches automatically the cases that have 85% or higher chances of being the same and suggests the proper matching in case of a lower value. Also, it shows all the possible matching values so you can decide the correct value if you don't like the one selected by the tool.